# How to trigger a method in another component in Vue3 (Composition API) if a global event bus is discouraged?

Tags: vuejs3

I have a component which lets me upload a file, and another component that shows the files that have been uploaded:

```
<FileUpload />
<FileList />
```

FileList has a refresh method that will get the latest files.
FileUpload has an emit "uploadFinished".

I would like to trigger a refresh of my FileList after an upload in FileUpload. What is the **"Vue way" of communicating between those components?**

I find the [official explanation](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#event-bus) rather disappointing. Bearing in mind that my components do not necessarily have to be siblings (or have any close relation for that matter), I am not sure how I can achieve this exclusively with VueX (which I am using).

I can trigger the loading of the files with an action, but inside my FileList I am doing other internal things as well, like setting a loading and resetting the GUI. **Those things cannot be controlled by data in my VueX State alone.**

```
const refresh = (pageNum = 0) => {
  collapseAll();
  isLoading.value = true;
  store.dispatch(LOAD_FILES_REQUEST, setParams(pageNum)).finally(() => {
    isLoading.value = false;
  });
};
```

To me, an **event Bus** seems to be the logical (and easiest) solution. Why is it frowned upon?

Comment: I will use Event Bus in this case...